# How do I compare one value to the previous and next X values in a dataframe in python

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

I want to find out if the previous X values and the next X values in a row are all lower than the n-th value. And if yes, I want to change the column 'isPeak' from 0 to 1. I have difficulty in finding out how to compare the previous and following values with the current one and wrote some pseudo-code into my for-loop:

```
X = 10
for i in range(len(df)):
    P = df.get_value(i, 'Price')
    if P >= *price(i-X:i+X)*:
        df.at[i, 'isPeak'] = 1
```

I need to replace the **price(i-X:i+X)** in a way that it compares all the X previous and X next prices with the current one. I found a solution that includes using shift() which adds the X previous and X next prices as additional columns. This makes it easier to compare them since I just need to find out if it is the highest value or not in this row. However, I would like for a more efficient or 'cleaner' version if that's possible and someone has an idea.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need somthing like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'price': np.arange(3,70,2)})
x=10
for i in range(x, df.shape[0] - x):
    P = df['price'].iloc[i]
    df_tmp = df.loc[i-x:i+x]
    if df_tmp['price'].loc[df_tmp['price']<=P].shape[0]>0:
        print('do something ...')
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried your solution and for the first couple of entries in the dataset it seems to classify the peaks correctly. That is, for the first ten entries it seems. Which could have to do with the fact that x is 10. Afterwards every entry gets classified as peak and is set to 1. This is how I implemented your code: `k=10
for i in range(k, df.shape[0] - k):
    P = df['Dow Chemical Company (The)'].iloc[i]
    df_tmp = df.loc[i-k:i+k]
    if df_tmp['Dow Chemical Company (The)'].loc[df_tmp['Dow Chemical Company (The)']<=P].shape[0]>0:
        df.at[i, 'isPeak'] = 1`